# How to trigger Openshift deployment when a repository changes?

Tags: openshift, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to configure continuous deployment with Openshift. I have sample React.js application which I want to deploy automatically when the new commit appears in the repository.

I created "application" and "build" and in Openshift, the build is deploying the web app to a new pod well (I used standard Node.js builder template). But it doesn't do it automatically when the code is updated in repo. How can I make Openshift build to observe the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: webhooks.

Openshift exposes so called webhooks. Source code repository (for example Bitbucket) can notify Openshift's build (using a web interface) when event like a push to the repository happens.

In build settings we have triggers section. We can configure new trigger with a specific secret. The triggers are visible in the configuration section of the build in read only mode then. They are the https addresses basically.

After creation of the trigger we can configure the repository to notify Openshift using webhook.